# Getting MODULE_NOT_FOUND error in Node.js/Nest.js

Tags: node.js, microservices, nestjs

I'm getting this when I'm trying to run microservice named -> accounts.

```
yarn run v1.22.5
$ nest start
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905

Error: Cannot find module '/home/node/services/accounts/dist/main'
     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
   requireStack: []
 }

 error Command failed with exit code 1.
 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

where, *accounts* is name of microservice.

I tried with running **yarn install** but still giving me same error.
Also, I tried with deleting *dist* folder and restarting microservice but the same issue persists.

Comment: When do you see this error? What are you running? Please add some more details to get the proper solution to your problem with this it will be difficult for anyone to understand what is wrong.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara I have updated it. I hope it is more clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It gets resolved after adding following entry in *nest-cli.json* file of my *accounts* microservice :

"entryFile": "services/accounts/src/main"